# No PDF output file and no error message

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmf, fmtutil

I am very new to LaTeX, please accept my apologies! A couple of months after finishing my dissertation with LaTeX, I want to run PDFLaTeX (Texmaker) again. However, no PDF output file is being generated and there is no error message. I have no clue what is happening, as I haven’t changed anything in the meanwhile. Here's a MWE that used to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The LOG FILE is very long, starting with:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)  (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.10.27) 27 OCT 2014 11:04
entering extended mode restricted \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Bsp 0.tex"
```

...and in the end it says:

```
Output written on "Bsp 0.pdf" (1 page, 21616 bytes).
PDF statistics:
16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

But the previous PDF is not replaced. Any ideas what might be the problem?

QUESTION UPDATE:

When I try to compile my dissertation (big file with multiple packages), the following warnings show up temporarily: [image: Error messages]

It says:

Warning: kpathesea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories:...

Failed to find cnffile fmtutil.cnf.

I searched for texmf.cnf and fmtutil.cnf on my computer but no such files were found. Furthermore, I updated Texmaker from Version 4.3 to 4.5 but it didn't change the outcome.

Do you have any suggestions how I could tackle this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. I assume when you say that "the previous PDF is not replaced", you actually have the previous pdf opened already in a reader. This can be an issue on some systems and some readers where the reader will lock the file. If you close the file and recompile, it should write the new pdf properly.

Comment: Are you sure there is no PDF? Because the log file says: _Output written on "Bsp 0.pdf" (1 page, 21616 bytes)._.

Comment: I edited your question a little because I do not think you meant to ask readers to apologise, but probably meant to say that you apologise. There is no need to apologise for being new to LaTeX, but I did not change your (presumably) intended meaning ;).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions! The previous version of the PDF was closed, otherwise it would have given me an error message when compiling, which is not the case. I also don't understand why it says 'output written on ...' when in fact no PDF is generated.

Comment: If those files are not on your computer, your TeX distribution is screwed up. You can either reinstall or try regenerating the configuration files first. (If only the config is screwed up, this is sensible, but it is hard to tell if more is corrupted or missing or not.) `tlmgr generate fmtutil --rebuild-sys` should regenerate the relevant config file, I think. `tlmgr generate --rebuild-sys` should regenerate the language files, I think. The help is a big unclear here as it only mentions language files but then says stuff involving `generate fmtutil`. `tlmgr --help` for information.